# client denied by server configuration

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to setup django project by apache and mod_wsgi file. But I am getting this error `client denied by server configuration: /home/ghrix/production` . I have google this errro and found lot of solutions but nothing worked for me.

My code are as follows :

**production.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys


sys.path = ['/home/ghrix/myproject/'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings'


import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**production.conf file :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ghrix/production.wsgi

ServerName firstweb.com
ServerAlias firstweb.com

Alias /static/ /home/ghrix/myproject/static/
 <Directory /home/ghrix/myproject/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            WSGIProcessGroup production
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Require all denied
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by making two changes : 
1)  **Require all denied**  -> change this to  -> **Require all granted**
2) If you look at the project created by you there is already a `wsgi.py` file in you project directory (same dir where your settings are placed by default) , So you do not have to create seperate wsgi file as I have created initially. Just point to that wsgi.py in your conf file inside apache2 as

`WSGIScriptAlias / /<path to my-project wsgi.py file>`

That's it you error is resolved. But still if you are getting one more error after this your **settings module is not find** then you have to edit your wsgi file and add two lines of code :

```
import sys
sys.path = ['<path to my project>'] + sys.path
```

That's it your project will run smoothly now.

So complete wsgi and conf files will look like this :

wsgi.py file :

```
import os
import sys

sys.path = ['<path to my project>'] + sys.path
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "conf.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /<path to my project>/wsgi.py

ServerName secondweb.com
ServerAlias secondweb.com

Alias /static/ /<path to my project>/static/
<Directory /<path to my project>/ >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```